# .then is not a function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Why is this line a valid promise:

```
const promise = Promise.resolve('Hello');
```

But not this:

```
const otherPromise = () => {
  return Promise.resolve('Hello');
}
```

When trying to call the second example with:

```
function runOtherPromise() {
  otherPromise
    .then(v => console.log(v));
}
```

...I get `TypeError: otherPromise.then is not a function`. It works fine with the first example, though. I don't understand why the second example doesn't return a promise.

Comment: `otherPromise().then(v => console.log(v));` will do the job!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

otherPromise is a function, you should call it like below:

```
runOtherPromise() {
    otherPromise()
        .then(v => console.log(v));
}
```